# How to test page header tags like meta tag, description etc with laravel dusk browser test?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-dusk

I want to test the description and the meta tag of a page with a Laravel Dusk browser test. How can I do this? I saw a spider test, but I could not get it work. How can I do this?

I tried a test like this: https://medium.com/@tushargugnani_54389/crawling-website-using-laravel-dusk-spider-bbbbe487a21

Comment: You can use `assertSourceHas()` or get the whole source with `$browser->driver->getPageSource()` and search it with regular expressions.

Comment: can you give an example of a assertSourceHas() to check the meta tag ?  @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: `$this->assertSourceHas('<meta name="description" content="Lorem ipsum.">');`

Comment: it worked wow.. thanks bro. @JonasStaudenmeir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `assertSourceHas()` with the tag's HTML:

```
$browser->assertSourceHas('<meta name="description" content="Lorem ipsum.">');
```